# Can't find correct Bootstrap 3 dropdown-menu state selector

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to style the state of the dropdown menu in Bootstrap 3 when it's clicked upon, but am unable to find the exact psuedoclass/selector to do so. It's unclear whether it renders the `background-color` or `background` transparent or black, and neither searching through BS3's bootstrap.css nor inspecting the live dropdown with the Web Developer plugin has given a definite answer. Furthermore, clicking on the dropdown menu seems to make the active `li` next to it have a slightly lighter background. Any insight on how to remedy either of these quirks is much appreciated.

Website: http://www.petebunke.com/newportfoliosite/sbmuseum

CSS (besides BootstrapCDN/FontAwesome/stickyfooter.css/jumbotron.css):
http://www.petebunke.com/newportfoliosite/sbmuseum/css/sbmuseum.css

Answer (score 0):

I would use Firefox to find out.

Press F12, and then pick "HTML" from the left pane, and "computed" from the right. Hover over the navbar, and I can see them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -

```
.navbar-nav >.open, .navbar-nav >.open >a{
     background: #471313 !important;
}
```

Check out this URL for better understanding of Bootstrap dropdown - http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-dropdowns.php